# Bootstrap 4 not initialising

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I created a HTML, CSS and JS file for a new design idea and wanted to involve bootstrap 4 in it.

Folder template looks like this:

```
 - projectFolder
  - index.html
   - css
     -- styles.css
   - js
     -- main.js
   - img
```

I added the links required in the header:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">`

but it **didn't seem to work.** After checking the link, I then decided to *copy and paste* the template from the bootstrap 4 website which looks like this: (I added Row's and Col's)

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
            shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
            crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="display-5">Hello, world!</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Assumenda nisi natus maxime quam nihil quae mollitia dicta
                deserunt error alias.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Assumenda nisi natus maxime quam nihil quae mollitia dicta
                deserunt error alias.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Assumenda nisi natus maxime quam nihil quae mollitia dicta
                deserunt error alias.
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I refresh the page, it looks like it's not initializing Bootstrap at all.

I'm at a loss as to what it could be.

Comment: Looks like the Bootstrap CDN server is down at the moment. you can try alternative resource cdn here [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Thank you for your response Afia Udofia , I thought it was something on my end, I'll check it out.

Comment: CDN loads for me. have you checked your console for any error??

Answer (score 0):

Afia mentioned that the CDN is down for Bootstrap.

I tried other CDN's that were shown to me, with no luck.

so I downloaded from [Bootstrap - Compiled CSS and JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/)

Linked it to the header, which worked for me.

> Which I am assuming will add a fraction to the load time, however
>   there isn't a lot of data for it to load so it should be fine for my
>   small project.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, please place your Custom CSS beneath that of Bootstrap, + remove slash "/" from your css at start

Comment: Hi Muhammad, it was because the Bootstrap CDN was down, downloading and implementing worked, but thankyou for your response.